# Mapping arrays with same values but different orders

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays of coordinates from two separate files from a CFD calculation. One is a mesh file which contains the connectivity information and the other is the results file.

My problem is that the coordinates from each file are not in the same order. What I would like to be able to do is order ALL the arrays from the results file to be in the same order as the mesh file.

My idea would be to find the matching values of xyz coordinates and create a mapping such that the rest of the result arrays can be ordered.

I was thinking something like:

```
mapping = np.empty(len(co_mesh))

for i,coord in enumerate(co_mesh):
    for j in range(len(co_res)):
        if (coord[0]==co_res[j,0]) and (coord[1]==co_res[j,1]) and (coord[2]==co_res[j,2]):
            mapping[i] = j
```

where co_mesh, co_res are arrays containing the x,y,z coords.

The problem is that I suspect this loop will take a long time. At the moment I'm only looping over around 70000 points but in future this could increase to 1 million or more.

Is there a faster way to write this in Python.

I'm using Python 2.6.5.

Ben

---

For those who are interested this is what I am currently using:

```
mesh_coords = zip(xm_list,ym_list,zm_list,range(len(x_po)))
res_coords = zip(xr_list,yr_list,zr_list,range(len(x)))

mesh_coords = sorted(mesh_coords , key = lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[2]))
res_coords = sorted(res_coords , key = lambda x:(x[0],x[1],x[2]))

mapping = zip(np.array(listym)[:,-1],np.array(listyr)[:,-1])

mapping = sorted(mapping , key = lambda x:(x[0]))
```

Comment: Have you looked at the interpolation functions of Scipy? http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about sorting coordinate vectors in both files along x than y and than least z coordinate?

You can do this efficient and fast if you use numpy arrays for vectors.

**Update:**

If you don't have the node ids of the nodes in the result mesh. But the coordinates are the same. Do the following:

Add a numbering as an additional information to your vectors. Sort both mesh by x,y,z add the now unsorted numbering of your mesh to your comesh and sort the comesh along that axis. Now the comesh contains the exact order as the original mesh.

Comment: I considered this but its also important to keep the connectivity arrays in order.

For example I have an array which contains the points which make up the vertices of a cell (in this case a cube), there are around 40000 cells involved. The number of the vertices in each of the connectivity arrays would then need to be mapped accordingly.

Comment: That looks good I just need to work out the sorting of xyz then I think I've got it. Thanks

Comment: If possible try to save your co mesh with nodeids. Allthough sorting works fine haveing node ids makes life much simpler.

Comment: What I'm trying to use np.lexsort with the array with an added index column. Lexsort doesn't seem to be sorting properly though, its wrong at the 12th decimal space

Comment: [lexsort](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html) does not change the coordinates. 12th decimal place is most likely some representation error when reading non binary numbers and converting the string back to double.